# Transform StringContent JSON into byte[]

Tags: c#, rest, dotnet-httpclient

Need to use this person converted into JSON inside the `byte[]` to finish the API. I've tried some different ways I found here, but I could not make it work. Help.

```
    static async void MakeRequest()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);

            var person = new Person();
            person.id = "1234";
            person.Name = "John Doe";
            person.Email = "  ";
            person.individualIdentificationCode = "0000";
            person.order = "1";
            person.action = "DIGITAL-SIGNATURE";
            person.signurl = "https://sandbox.portaldeassinaturas.com.br/Assinatura/AssinarEletronicoFrame/152124?chave=";

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person);
            var data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            
            // Request headers
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Token", "{}");

            var uri = "https://api-sbx.portaldeassinaturas.com.br/api/v2/document/create?" + queryString;

            HttpResponseMessage response;

            // Request body
            byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

            using (var content = new ByteArrayContent(byteData))
            {
                content.Headers.ContentType = new 
 MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/Json");
                response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please _always_ add code and errormessages as **text**, not image.

Comment: Just post the StringContent instead of the ByteArrayContent, the client will do the appropriate conversion.

Comment: [`StringContent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.stringcontent?view=netcore-3.1) "is-a" `ByteArrayContent` ( .. "is-a" `HttpContent`). So just pass it to `PostAsync`. Should work.

Comment: BTW, the error you are seeing is because `GetBytes` expects a `char[]` or `string`. But you are trying to pass a `StringContent` typed object and there is no conversion available to the compiler. But as said above: you don't even need that.

Comment: just put the "data" in the response at the end ? delete the byte[] part ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are seeing is because `GetBytes` expects a [`char[]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getbytes?view=net-5.0#System_Text_Encoding_GetBytes_System_Char___) or [`string`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getbytes?view=net-5.0#System_Text_Encoding_GetBytes_System_String_). But you are trying to pass a [`StringContent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.stringcontent?view=netcore-3.1) typed object and there is no conversion available to the compiler. **But:** you don't even need that!

Since `StringContent` "is-a" `ByteArrayContent` ( .. "is-a" `HttpContent`, which is expected by `PostAsync`), just pass it to `PostAsync`:

```
response = await client.PostAsync(uri, data);
```

---

**AND** as always, of course: Don't create a new HttpClient in every call!

> HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and re-used throughout the life of an application. Instantiating an HttpClient class for every request will exhaust the number of sockets available under heavy loads. This will result in SocketException errors. -
> [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-5.0)